# Create symboling link under same folder

Tags: shell, symlink

```
test
---> First
------> Inside-First
----------> Cool1
---> Second
------> Inside-Second
----------> Cool2
```

I want to create a symbolic clink between Inside-First to Inside-Second folder, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ln -sv ./test/First/Inside-First ./test/Second/Inside-Second/new_symlink
```